# FreeSWITCH - how can i make the call, talk to the person and then add him to the conference?

Tags: voip, freeswitch, telecommunication

I followed there official documentation ( https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Conference+Add+Call+Example ) but its not working for me.

When i make a call to a person he does not join the conference, but how can i let him join the conference and stay even i disconnect my call?

For example i am trying as following:

1 - Stackoverflow experts consulting is required by me and my other colleuges

2 - me and my other colleuges we joined a conference room

3 - now we need stackoverflow programmer give us 30 minutes of lecture so we call him up (me as admin here)

4 - when i am talking with stackoverflow nobody in the conference hearing stackoverflow experts.

So how can i bring him in the conference please?

```
<include>
  <!-- Sample dialplan for sending member or moderator to a conference where he/she can add/remove calls -->
  <!-- Dial 46xx for member, *46xx for moderator -->
    <extension name="Simple add-caller conf: member">
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(46\d{2})$">
    <action application="answer"/>
    <action application="conference" data="$1@simple"/>
     </condition>
    </extension>

    <extension name="Simple add-caller conf: moderator">
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^\*(46\d{2}$)">
    <action application="answer"/>
    <!-- set up a few bind_digit_action (BDA) bindings for the moderator -->
        <action application="bind_digit_action" data="moderator,*1,exec:execute_extension,ASK_FOR_NUMBER__$1 XML default"/>
    <action application="bind_digit_action" data="moderator,*2,exec:execute_extension,CANCEL_LAST_CALL__$1 XML default"/>
    <action application="digit_action_set_realm" data="moderator"/>
    <action application="conference" data="$1@simple+flags{moderator}"/>
      </condition>
    </extension>

    <extension name="Add new OB call to conference">
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^ASK_FOR_NUMBER__(\d+)$">
    <!-- ask caller for a number + #, collect into ${target_num} variable -->
    <action application="play_and_get_digits" data="4 20 1 5000 # ivr/ivr-enter_destination_telephone_number.wav ivr/ivr-that_was_an_invalid_entry.wav target_num \d+"/>
    <!-- add this call to the conference -->
    <action application="execute_extension" data="${target_num}"/>
      </condition>
    </extension>

    <extension name="Remove last OB call added to conference">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^CANCEL_LAST_CALL__(\d+)$">
          <!-- remove a call from the conference -->
           <action application="play_and_get_digits" data="4 11 1 5000 # ivr/ivr-enter_destination_telephone_number.wav ivr/ivr-that_was_an_invalid_entry.wav target_num \d+"/>
           <action application="set" data="res=${uuid_kill ${hash(select/domain-${domain_name}/last_user_${target_num})}}"/>
        </condition>
    </extension>

    <extension name="add that call">
    <!-- if we have a four-digit number then attempt to dial it as a user ... -->
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d{4})$" break="on-true">
        <action application="set" data="new_uuid=${create_uuid foo}" inline="true"/>
        <action application="hash" data="insert/domain-${domain_name}/last_user_$1/${new_uuid}" />
        <action application="set" data="res=${bgapi originate {origination_uuid=${new_uuid}}user/$1 &conference(${conference_name})}"/>
      </condition>
    <!-- if we have a five+ digit number then attempt to dial it as a gw connection ... -->
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d{5})$" break="on-true">
        <action application="set" data="new_uuid=${create_uuid foo}" inline="true"/>
        <action application="hash" data="insert/domain-${domain_name}/last_user_$1/${new_uuid}" />
        <action application="set" data="res=${bgapi originate {origination_uuid=${new_uuid}}sofia/gateway/voipbuster/$1 &conference(${conference_name})}"/>
      <!-- Alternatively, you can just use loopback, but that creates three call legs instead of one, so be warned -->
      <!--
                   <action application="set" data="res=${bgapi originate {origination_uuid=${new_uuid}}loopback/$1 &conference(${conference_name})}"/>
      -->
      </condition>
    <!-- ... otherwise inform moderator that the operation was not exactly successful -->
      <condition field="destination_number" expression="^$">
        <action application="playback" data="ivr/ivr-dude_you_suck.wav"/>
      </condition>
    </extension>
</include>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `bgdial` and `dial` in [mod_conference](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_conference) documentation.

What you are doing, looks quite OK, and needs debugging. But with `conference dial` you would have it easier.

Comment: How to use it from XML please?

Comment: My problem is i can call from conference but i cant connect that person into the conference.

Comment: Also when i disconnect the call with him he also get disconnected, the idea is to hold him and let him join the conference after then i have to leave but he will continue the conversation.

Comment: if you build a test server where we could look together, that would help. it needs debugging and looking at what's happening.

Comment: Can i send you email to this address ssinyagin at-sign k-open.com?

Comment: Yes, I'm very easy to find :)

Comment: Please check your email. i have sent you login details for to test *4600 and dial *1 to call your mobile or landline and then bring your mobile, landline into that FreeSWITCH conference room name: 4600 . So that others can join that room by general SIP accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You should use call conference that will make your objective lot more easier.

Use Lua script called by XML dialplan:

```
function call_to_agent()
    session:execute("conference_set_auto_outcall","user/[user_that_you_want]")
    session:execute("conference","conference_name@default")
end

session:answer()
call_to_agent()
```